# Whats the way to find that given string is proper date time format in itcl?

Tags: tcl, itcl

I have this code which takes the values as 1hours/2hours or 3am /4pm, or 1week, 2week, 24hours etc, in time and date formats, and I have this if condition which validates for semantics :

```
 if {[catch {clock scan [getValue]} errMsg]} \
    {
        handleError -errMsg \
            "Invalid date-time format: $errMsg."
    }
```

So any other alternative for this which takes less time/uses CPU to validate the same?

Comment: Parsing is always expensive and is going to take a lot of resources.   If you can pre-convert the possible inputs, it would be faster.   Is the input from a GUI or command line or ?  If you can't pre-convert, perhaps you can cache results of the conversion.

Comment: @BradLanam the input is from CommandLine, how is caching of results done here?

Comment: If this is not in a loop, why are you worried about CPU/processing speed?